# I can't connect in stmp auth with laravel 5.5 using swift transport

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer, smtp-auth, microsoft-oauth

I try connect using $transport->setAuthMode('XOAUTH2') and using the token but always i get error 535 same being all credentials right and in azure ad also.

I would like to connect me using the token and also i want to know if it's possible connect me using the same token created for imap.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.